# ESRI Silverlight Cartography - Looking at whats not there

Tags: cartography, spatial-statistics, silverlight, arcgis-silverlight-api

I have line data that has been symbolozied in ways that I don't have time to understand and would like to make a map that tells me =).

My general question is how to display the lack of data results for queries.  I have a bunch of layer files that were built with a bunch of def queries in ArcMap.  I will iterate over the line data and for each unique line check for results of applying a def query.  If results are returned, a new layer file is created representing that query.

I want to highlight the queries that didn't return results in a silverlight app.  So I have all the queries that returned zero records in a database.

I'll be making this map with silverlight but any solid cartography concepts for getting at what's not there are welcome.

Comment: "highlight the queries that didn't return results" ... does this mean you want to highlight the query string?

Comment: Perhaps report it in a graph.. spatially located near those queries that did return results and some how shown relationship to line entities that also didn't return results?